# Trouble projecting WRF data in R

Tags: r, raster, projection, netcdf

I am working with WRF climate data (4km resolution for North America, available here: https://rda.ucar.edu/datasets/ds612.0/index.html#!description).  The data format is netcdf.  I would like to read the data in as a raster and project the data into lat/lon coordinates using R. I would like to do this so I can extract spatial subsets of the data and use raster algebra.  However, I am having trouble projecting the data.

There has been a lot written online about WRF projections and how tricky they are to work with (see [this](https://fabienmaussion.info/2018/01/06/wrf-projection/) and [this](https://journals.ametsoc.org/doi/full/10.1175/MWR-D-12-00351.1)).

To start with I've been using the file of constants (lat, lon, terrain height, soil type, etc).  It is available here from the original source: https://rda.ucar.edu/datasets/ds612.0/index.html#cgi-bin/datasets/getWebList?dsnum=612.0&action=customize&disp=&gindex=1, it is called RALconus_4km_wrf_constants.nc.   I've made a copy of the file available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ipHVP9_uF3Y-9IfIq52OdsDgJroPgLW9/view?usp=sharing). This file contains a field 'HGT' (terrain height) with dimensions [west_east,south_north,Time] as well as fields 'XLAT' and 'XLONG' with dimensions [west_east,south_north]. The latitude and longitude values are unique for each grid cell.  From print(nc):

```
Time  Size:1   *** is unlimited ***
        units: hours since 1901-01-01 00:00:00
        calendar: standard
        long_name: Time
        description: Time
    south_north  Size:1015
    west_east  Size:1359
```

I know from the WRF documentation ([here](http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/users/docs/user_guide_V3/users_guide_chap3.htm)), that the projection is lambert conformal conic, and the netcdf file provides a few additional details:

```
    110 global attributes:
    TITLE:  OUTPUT FROM WRF V3.4.1 MODEL
    START_DATE: 2001-02-28_00:00:00
    SIMULATION_START_DATE: 2000-10-01_00:00:00
    WEST-EAST_GRID_DIMENSION: 1360
    SOUTH-NORTH_GRID_DIMENSION: 1016
    BOTTOM-TOP_GRID_DIMENSION: 51
    DX: 4000
    DY: 4000
    GRIDTYPE: C
    DIFF_OPT: 1
    KM_OPT: 4
    DAMP_OPT: 3
    DAMPCOEF: 0.200000002980232
    KHDIF: 0
    KVDIF: 0
    MP_PHYSICS: 28
    RA_LW_PHYSICS: 4
    RA_SW_PHYSICS: 4
    SF_SFCLAY_PHYSICS: 11
    SF_SURFACE_PHYSICS: 4
    BL_PBL_PHYSICS: 1
    CU_PHYSICS: 0
    SURFACE_INPUT_SOURCE: 1
    SST_UPDATE: 1
    GRID_FDDA: 2
    GFDDA_INTERVAL_M: 360
    GFDDA_END_H: 999999
    GRID_SFDDA: 0
    SGFDDA_INTERVAL_M: 0
    SGFDDA_END_H: 0
    HYPSOMETRIC_OPT: 2
    SF_URBAN_PHYSICS: 0
    SHCU_PHYSICS: 0
    MFSHCONV: 0
    FEEDBACK: 0
    SMOOTH_OPTION: 2
    SWRAD_SCAT: 1
    W_DAMPING: 1
    MOIST_ADV_OPT: 1
    SCALAR_ADV_OPT: 1
    TKE_ADV_OPT: 1
    DIFF_6TH_OPT: 0
    DIFF_6TH_FACTOR: 0.119999997317791
    FGDT: 0
    GUV: 4.99999987368938e-05
    GT: 4.99999987368938e-05
    GPH: 4.99999987368938e-05
    IF_RAMPING: 1
    DTRAMP_MIN: 60
    OBS_NUDGE_OPT: 0
    BUCKET_MM: 100
    BUCKET_J: 1e+09
    PREC_ACC_DT: 60
    OMLCALL: 0
    ISFTCFLX: 0
    ISHALLOW: 0
    OPT_SFC: 1
    DVEG: 4
    OPT_CRS: 1
    OPT_BTR: 2
    OPT_RUN: 1
    OPT_FRZ: 1
    OPT_INF: 1
    OPT_RAD: 3
    OPT_ALB: 2
    OPT_SNF: 4
    OPT_TBOT: 1
    OPT_STC: 1
    DFI_OPT: 0
    WEST-EAST_PATCH_START_UNSTAG: 1
    WEST-EAST_PATCH_END_UNSTAG: 1359
    WEST-EAST_PATCH_START_STAG: 1
    WEST-EAST_PATCH_END_STAG: 1360
    SOUTH-NORTH_PATCH_START_UNSTAG: 1
    SOUTH-NORTH_PATCH_END_UNSTAG: 1015
    SOUTH-NORTH_PATCH_START_STAG: 1
    SOUTH-NORTH_PATCH_END_STAG: 1016
    BOTTOM-TOP_PATCH_START_UNSTAG: 1
    BOTTOM-TOP_PATCH_END_UNSTAG: 50
    BOTTOM-TOP_PATCH_START_STAG: 1
    BOTTOM-TOP_PATCH_END_STAG: 51
    GRID_ID: 1
    PARENT_ID: 0
    I_PARENT_START: 1
    J_PARENT_START: 1
    PARENT_GRID_RATIO: 1
    DT: 15
    CEN_LAT: 39.7000122070312
    CEN_LON: -98
    TRUELAT1: 28
    TRUELAT2: 50
    MOAD_CEN_LAT: 39.7000122070312
    STAND_LON: -98
    POLE_LAT: 90
    POLE_LON: 0
    GMT: 0
    JULYR: 2001
    JULDAY: 59
    MAP_PROJ: 1
    MMINLU: MODIFIED_IGBP_MODIS_NOAH
    NUM_LAND_CAT: 20
    ISWATER: 17
    ISLAKE: -1
    ISICE: 15
    ISURBAN: 13
    ISOILWATER: 14
    Conventions: CF-1.6
    history: Tue Apr  4 15:29:54 2017: ncks -A mylatlon4.nc myclean.nc
    history_of_appended_files: Tue Apr  4 15:29:54 2017: Appended file mylatlon4.nc had no "history" attribute

    NCO: "4.5.5"
```

I am starting by trying to project the HGT field. The raw data from the HGT field from the netcdf file looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FihpU.jpg).

[image]

In my attempts to properly project the raster, I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36868506/how-to-change-a-lambert-conic-conformal-raster-projection-to-latlon-degree-r/36869273#36869273) and other posts, but I have not been successful yet.  I have tried the following code and variants of it:

```
  wrfdir <- '/Volumes/Web/abby/DATA/WRF/'
  metafn <- paste0(wrfdir, 'RALconus4km_wrf_constants.nc')
  rr <- raster(metafn,varname='HGT')
  projection(rr) <- '+proj=lcc +lat_1=28.0 +lat_2=50.0 +lat_0=39.7000122070312 +lon_0=-98.0 +ellps=sphere +a=6370000 +b=6370000 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs'
  # then project to lat lon
  rrLL = projectRaster(rr, crs="+init=epsg:4326")
  plot(rrLL[[1]])
```

This results in the following map, in which the lats and lons are obviously incorrect:
[first projection attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjQAs.jpg)

[image]

I have also tried the following, based on this [post](http://r-sig-geo.2731867.n2.nabble.com/adapting-spatial-points-and-wrld-smpl-to-a-reference-system-implicit-in-a-nc-file-tt7589570.html):

```
 crs(rr) <- '+proj=longlat +ellps=sphere +a=6370000 +b=6370000 +units=m +no_defs' 
 rrLL <- projectRaster((rr),crs='+proj=lcc +lat_1=28.0 +lat_2=50.0 +lat_0=39.7000122070312 +lon_0=-98.0 +ellps=sphere +a=6370000 +b=6370000 +units=m +no_defs')
```

Which results in the following error message:

```
Error in if (nr != x@nrows | nc != x@ncols) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In rgdal::rawTransform(projfrom, projto, nrow(xy), xy[, 1], xy[,  :
634 projected point(s) not finite
2: In rgdal::rawTransform(projection(obj), crs, nrow(xy), xy[, 1],  :
4 projected point(s) not finite
```

Any thoughts on how to do this would be much appreciated!

Comment: These might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36868506/how-to-change-a-lambert-conic-conformal-raster-projection-to-latlon-degree-r

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30287065/convert-lambert-conformal-conic-projection-to-wgs84-in-r

Comment: Thanks @Tung, I've looked at both of those and tried modifying them to fit my situation, but neither has worked for me.  Note, I'm not using 'getRaster' since that downloads different WRF data.

Comment: can you make the file available for downloading? The link you provide requires a login.

Comment: I added a link above to a copy of the file.  It can be found here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ipHVP9_uF3Y-9IfIq52OdsDgJroPgLW9/view?usp=sharing

Comment: have you tried star? You could read data with raster, then convert to stars and then project with st_transform https://github.com/r-spatial/stars